# Laravel: Auth class after login is not working

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 5.7. I am stuck on one thing. After redirecting to next page I am not able to get the logged in user properties.
`Auth::user()->id` is returning me error of getting unknown property of undefined.

`Auth::check()` also returning me `false`. I have checked lot of questions on the stack and other platforms but none of them solve my problem.

Here is what I have tried so far:
View:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label>{{ __('lang.email_address') }}</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('lang.email') }}">
        @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif  
    </div>
    <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <label>{{ __('lang.password') }}</label> 
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('lang.password') }}">
        @if ($errors->has('password'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
            </span>
            @endif  

    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" > {{ __('lang.remember_me') }}
        </label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat m-b-30 m-t-30 bg-login"> {{ __('lang.sign_in') }}</button>
    <hr/>
    <div class="register-link m-t-15 text-center">
        <p>
            {{ __('lang.forgot_your_password') }} <a href="{{Url('admin/forget-password')}}">  {{ __('lang.click_to_reset') }}</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
     $validator = validator($request->all(),[
        'email'=>'required|email',
        'password'=>'required'
    ]);
     if($validator->fails()) {
         return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
     }
     $user = User::where('role_id', User::ROLE_ADMIN)->where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();
     if(!empty($user)){
        $userdata = array(
            'email'=>$request->input('email'),
            'password'=>$request->input('password')
        );
        if(Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
            return redirect('/admin')->with('success', trans('lang.login_success'));
        } else {
            return redirect('/admin/login')->withInput()->with('error', trans('lang.incorrect_email_password'));
        }
     }else{
         return redirect('/admin/login')->with('error',trans('lang.you_are_not_allowed_action'));
     }
}
```

I am redirecting to the admin page but it gives error of Auth class.

Comment: Does it show the error `incorrect_email_password` after redirecting?  also tell where it redirects?

Comment: Update your question with the laravel error

Answer (score 1):

you did not define Auth class in your controller. define it like this:

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
```

Comment: I have defined. I have not shared complete controller file but only the function required. All the required classes and namespaces are added properly.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to define use Auth on the top of the controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Comment: I have defined. I have not shared complete controller file but only the function required. All the required classes and namespaces are added properly

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have problem with Auth class so try with one of these codes

```
\Auth::check()

\Auth::user()->id
```

or

```
auth()->check()

auth()->user()->id
```